# Create toolbar with event in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

Hi I'm having a problem with my single-document MFC application.

I want to add my own toolbar to MainFrm class (CFrameWnd).

I am a total newb with MFC. So I'm not sure that's even the place to add it.

So far:

A toolbar resource with id IDR_TOOLBAR1 is created

A toolbarbutton with id ID_SELECT_SHAPE

In MainFrm.h is `CToolBar m_wndMyToolBar;` declared

In MainFrm.cpp:

```
if (!m_wndMyToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
            !m_wndMyToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```

The toolbar is showing now. YAY!

But I don't know how to add the event handler.

Somebody who can tell if I'm on the right track? And if so, who can tell how to add that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.  Your MainFrame.cpp should have a section that starts with

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
```

and ends with

```
END_MESSAGE_MAP
```

Inside that section, you will need an entry

```
ON_COMMAND  (ID_SELECT_SHAPE, &CFrameWnd::OnSelectShape)
```

In your .h file add a declaration

```
afx_msg void OnSelectShape();
```

and in the .cpp file implement the OnSelectShape function to handle your event.

Depending on what your handler needs to do and what data it needs to have, it may be easier to add the handler and implement it in the CView... class instead of the CFrameWnd class.  Handlers can also be implemented in the CDocument... class.  When the toolbar button is clicked, the MFC Doc-View framework will first look for a handler in the View.  If there is no handler available, it then looks for one in the Document, and finally if there is not a handler there it will look for one in the main Frame window.

Comment: Thanks! I see now that there was such a section already so I added that entry. But now I get the error: `'ID_SELECT_SHAPE' : undeclared identifier`. And I'm sure it is in my resources

Comment: Oh wait.. Now its doing something. A full rebuild did the trick. And your solution worked flawless. +1!